# Regex to remove trailing string in .htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My web server is appending unwanted extra characters to the ends of URLs and I would like to remove these. My current RewriteRule is...

```
RewriteRule ([0-9]{4})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/(.*) https://example.com/$4 [R=301,L]
```

This takes `http://example.com/2021/06/19/page-name` and converts it to `http://example.com/page-name`.

The problem with this rule is the wildcard, anything after page-name is also included, such as `https://example.com/page-name/%s`. How can I modify this rule to omit anything after `$4`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess Rule. Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/([^/]*).*/?$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

***Explanation:*** You need not to create 4 capturing groups here, just match from starting of url 4 digits/2 digits/2 digits and then capture everything till next occurrence of `/` in 1st capturing group, which could be used in redirection part.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't seem to work. I used https://example.com/2021/06/19/post-name/test and it redirected to https://example.com/post-name/test I tried from an Incognito browser to avoid cache issues.

Comment: @AidanKnight, not sure why this didn't work for you. Could you please do check `RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/([^/]*)(.*)/?$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]` once and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: My apologies, the example in your original post worked. I forgot that Open Litespeed had to be restarted for HTACCESS files to take effect. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You may use this rule:

```sh
RewriteRule ^\d{4})(?:/\d{2}){2}/([\w-]+).* /$1 [R=301,L]
```

There is no need to capture anything that you don't need so removed capture groups of date fields.

Also `[\w-]+` will match 1+ of word or hyphen characters to match a page-name and that is the only thing you want to capture, to be used in the redirect target on RHS.

If you want to include more characters in page-name then consider:

```
RewriteRule ^\d{4})(?:/\d{2}){2}/([^/]+)/.* /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Where `[^/]+` will match 1+ of any character that is not `/`